# How to calculate cubic spline terms using max function in R?

Tags: r

I'm running into problems manually calculating cubic spline terms for a regression in R.

I'll use the `mtcars` dataset as an example, where I'll create a knot at disp = 200:

```
mtcars$disp_knot_200 <- apply(mtcars, 1, function(x) (max(0, (mtcars$disp - 200)))^3)
head(mtcars)
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb disp_knot_200
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4      20123648
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4      20123648
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1      20123648
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1      20123648
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2      20123648
Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1      20123648
```

As you can see, R is not finding the maximum value of either `0` or `mtcars$disp - 200`, but instead is returning the maximum for the entire column.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your apply you are never using `x`. Instead you can use `pmax` like:

```
pmax(0, (mtcars$disp - 200))^3
```

or change mtcars$disp with x["disp"] in your apply:

```
apply(mtcars, 1, function(x) (max(0, (x["disp"] - 200)))^3)
```

or use `sapply`:

```
sapply(mtcars$disp-200, max, 0)^3
```

to get the desired terms.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you! I knew there was simple solution I was overlooking.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the `pmax` approach, you can also use `ifelse` like below to make it

```
within(mtcars,disp_knot_200 <- ifelse(disp > 200, (disp-200)^3, 0))
```